# R Shinydashboard change witdh property of box in server side

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs, shinydashboard

I create my first app with R-Shinydashboard.

I use a box command (witdh=6) to plot inside (using dygraphs).I need change witdh property in server side to maximized the selected plot (change to width=12)

Thanks for all.

Comment: Could you post a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), maybe just an app with two charts so we can play around?

Comment: dygraph() as default will fill the box it is in, have you put it in a box(width=12, ...) function?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't put images.

But, I have 2 boxes (width=6) in two columns. Every box have in the title position on actionbutton. When I press this button I like change the width property to 12., width this I can see the plot (dygraphs) maximized to max. window.

I will press one button and see the plot(dygraphs) maximized in this box or another window.

Thanks for all.